# How to repair the checksum of the non-volatile memory (NVM) of Intel Ethernet Controller I219-V of an ASUS laptop?

Tags: linux, drivers, ethernet, oem, asus-laptop

I have a problem with a new [ASUSPRO B8430UA](http://www.asus.com/Commercial-Notebooks/ASUSPRO-B8430UA/specifications/) laptop: its [Intel Ethernet Connection I219-V](http://ark.intel.com/products/82186/Intel-Ethernet-Connection-I219-V) does not work under Linux.  In fact, I tried two different laptops of this model, and both had the same problem.

The Linux driver used is [*e1000e*](https://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/), it produces the following messages during Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) boot:

```
$ dmesg | grep e1000e 
[ 5.643760] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k 
[ 5.643761] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation. 
[ 5.644308] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode 
[ 5.877838] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid 
[ 5.907340] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -5
```

I have tried installing the latest version 3.3.4 of *e1000e*, but this didn't help (I have tainted the kernel, though).

I have posed questions about this on [*e1000-devel*](https://sourceforge.net/p/e1000/mailman/e1000-devel/) mailing list, and it was advised that I contact my laptop manufacturer, because "The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid" means that the contents of the non-volatile memory of my Ethernet chip is corrupted, or at least that it does not match the checksum (unfortunately, I am not a specialist and cannot explain this more precisely).

I have posed the question to Intel customer support, and they replied that they do not take care of OEM systems (on-board Ethernet chips in laptops) and that I should contact ASUS:

> Unfortunately as your system is OEM our support options are extremely limited. The laptop manufacturer may have altered the software or the hardware and this is why support and drivers for such systems is provided directly by the laptop manufacturer.

I have contacted ASUS customer support, but they replied that they have no tools for checking or reparing the contents of the NVM, and that if I find such tools, they would be glad to know about it.  They also explained that they are only supposed to support the original hardware and software configuration, and this laptop model is sold with Windows 7.  Under Windows 7 my Ethernet seems to work fine.  According to what I've learned, Windows simply doesn't check the NVM checksum.

I have found that in one similar case in 2011, the problem could be fixed using [Intel Ethernet Connections Boot Utility](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19186):

> https://thesorcerer.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/guide-intel-82573l-gigabit-ethernet-with-ubuntu-11-04-and-fix-pxe-e05/

However, the DISCLAIMER in the last paragraph warns:

> You probably need to know that the Intel(R) Ethernet Connections Boot Utility WAS NOT designed to be used with on board (also know as OEM) lan cards (is for the PCI cards) therefore there is no sure way to predict it’s interactions with others on board components like USB or SOUND controllers.

The [description](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/19186/eng/bootutil.txt) of BootUtil version 1.6.13.0 also seems to say that it is not exactly intended for use with on-board Ethernet controllers:

> The Intel(R) Ethernet Flash Firmware Utility (BootUtil) is a utility that can be used to program the PCI option ROM on the flash memory of supported Intel PCI and PCI-Express-based network adapters, and to update configurations.
>
> [...]
>
> OEMs may provide custom flash firmware images for OEM network adapters. Please refer to the instructions given by OEMs.

There is however a paragraph I didn't understand:

> PXE+EFI and iSCSI+EFI image combinations are supported for all OEM generic adapters, however support is limited to devices which support both technologies as discrete images.

Besides, in [comment 5](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=459202#c5) on a 2008 issue where the [NVM was getting corrupted](http://lwn.net/Articles/300202/) because of a e1000e driver [bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11382), it is advised:

> Please DO NOT run ibautil as some sites on the web suggest to try to fix this issue.  It will likely cause you to have to replace your motherboard to get LAN functionality back.

IBAUTIL is one of the predecessors of BootUtil.

In any case, I decided to run BootUtil from under Linux without command-line options to get the "list of all supported Intel network ports found in the system."  This is what I've got:

```
$ sudo ./bootutil64e

Intel(R) Ethernet Flash Firmware Utility
BootUtil version 1.6.13.0
Copyright (C) 2003-2016 Intel Corporation

Type BootUtil -? for help

Port Network Address Location Series  WOL Flash Firmware                Version
==== =============== ======== ======= === ============================= =======
  1   D017C2201F59     0:31.6 Gigabit N/A FLASH Not Present
```

I would like to understand what "FLASH Not Present" means in this context, and what options I have for fixing the checksum.

---

**Update 1.**
According to a comment I received from *e1000-devel* mailing list about "FLASH Not Present",

> The flash and NVM are two separate items.  The flash enables things
> like PXE booting and iSCSI whereas the NVM stores things like the
> Network Address.

---

**Update 2.**
I have found Intel's [datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/ethernet-connection-i219-datasheet.pdf) for I219, Section 10.3.2.2 *Checksum Word Calculation* says:

> The Checksum word (Word 0x3F, NVM bytes 0x7E and 0x7F) is used to ensure that the base NVM image is a valid image. The value of this word should be calculated such that after adding all the words (0x00- 0x3F) / bytes (0x00-0x7F), including the Checksum word itself, the sum should be 0xBABA. The initial value in the 16 bit summing register should be 0x0000 and the carry bit should be ignored after each addition.

Comment: Have you tried patching the checksum validation out of the driver?

Comment: No, i haven't.  As far as i have understood, it is expected to work; however, it would be a lot of hassle for me to maintain such system, and it would not fix the root cause.

Comment: I have NVRAM cards for servers, that need a patch on every kernel update, and a simple DKMS script sorted this out, just apt-get upgrade and it works on reboot. I don't think the root cause is fixable: IIUC you simply don't have NVM, as it is not needed if you use your NIC only from the OS, which is mostly true for Laptops.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but i am not too much into scripting kernel module patching.  I do not understand what it means that i "do not have NVM" (where would it disappear? why neither ASUS nor Intel support mentioned it?).  If this is indeed so, then maybe e1000e should have noticed it and didn't try to check the checksum, shouldn't it?

Comment: The output of bootutil64e and the driver messages make me think, that your OEM chose to simply not build NVM into the system, as it is not needed for a typical laptop role running Windows.

Comment: @EugenRieck, if it is so, then IMO the problem should be addressed by e1000e driver, which should detect that there is no NVM and not check it.  However it looks unlikely to me that e1000e would be able to read the NVM successfully, while it is not there, and only detect the checksum mismatch.  Unless the NVM is read in a loop which is never executed, and the accumulated checksum remains 0.  The first level of ASUS customer support seems to know nothing about this NVM, i'll see if i can get more information on this from Intel or ASUS.

Comment: Would it not be easier just to buy a USB to Ethernet adapter?

Comment: Well, it is definitely not easier than having a working Ethernet port from the beginning.  It is a completely new laptop, i have just received it in exchange of another one which in addition to this problem had another one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before trying my solution, please consider trying [the one](https://superuser.com/a/1188020) by [ppparadox](https://superuser.com/users/426041/ppparadox) first.

---

With kind help from [*e1000-devel*](https://sourceforge.net/p/e1000/mailman/e1000-devel/) mailing list, here is how I fixed the NVM *Checksum word* using [`ethtool`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ethtool8.html).

**tl;dr:** *Basically, I first patched e1000e to have access to the Ethernet chip in Linux, and then used `ethtool` to read a value from the "checksummed" region of the NVM of my I219-V and then to write it back.  The writing operation fixed the checksum.*

To have acces to my Ethernet chip from Linux, I had to patch *e1000e* to skip NVM checksum validation.  In file `src/netdev.c`, I changed the first line of

```c
for (i = 0;; i++) {
    if (e1000_validate_nvm_checksum(&adapter->hw) >= 0)
        break;
    if (i == 2) {
        dev_err(pci_dev_to_dev(pdev),
            "The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid\n");
        err = -EIO;
        goto err_eeprom;
    }
}
```

into

```c
for (i = 0; false; i++) {
```

(The whole block could also be just removed or commented out.)

Then I installed the patched module.  From the `/src` directory I did:

```sh
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r e1000e
sudo modprobe e1000e
sudo update-initramfs -u
reboot
```

Now the checksum validation was skipped and the Ethernet started working.

Before fixing the Checksum word, I looked into the outline of the NVM of I219 presented in Section 10 of Intel's [datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/ethernet-connection-i219-datasheet.pdf).
The use of Checksum word is explained in Section 10.3.2.2.

I noted the Checksum word before writing to the NVM:

```
$ sudo ethtool -e enp0s31f6 offset 0x7e length 2
Offset      Values
------      ------
0x007e:     60 13
```

(`enp0s31f6` is the name of my Ethernet interface.)  Thus the erroneous Checksum word value was `0x1360`.

I looked at the dump of NVM with `sudo ethtool -e enp0s31f6` and then looked again at the byte at offset 0x10:

```
$ sudo ethtool -e enp0s31f6 offset 0x10 length 1
Offset      Values
------      ------
0x0010:     ff
```

(Apparently any location would do, but I was told that in my case the value at offset 0x10 was not used at all, so it seemed "safer.")

For writing to the NVM (EEPROM) with `ethtool`, I needed a "magic key."  I read [*Unbricking an Intel Pro/1000 (e1000) network interface*](http://blog.vodkamelone.de/archives/146-Unbricking-an-Intel-Pro1000-e1000-network-interface.html) and figured out that my magic key was `0x15708086` using `lspci -nn`:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep Ethernet
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-V [8086:1570] (rev 21)
```

Then I wrote `0xff` back to offset 0x10 in the NVM:

```
$ sudo ethtool -E enp0s31f6 magic 0x15708086 offset 0x10 value 0xff
```

After comparing the dumps of the NVM before and after the write, I could see that, as expected, the only thing that changed was the Checksum word:

```
$ sudo ethtool -e enp0s31f6 offset 0x7e length 2
Offset      Values
------      ------
0x007e:     60 93
```

The new value thus was `0x9360`.

I booted a kernel with an unpatched *e1000e*, and the Ethernet port worked fine.

P.S.  I find it a bit worrying that only the highest bit in the Checksum word was wrong.

Comment: To make the NVM writable, I had to add the `WriteProtectNVM=0` parameter to my `modprobe`/`insmod` call.

Comment: I can confirm that this fix worked with [e1000e version 3.5.3.3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/e1000e%20stable/3.3.5.3/) on desktop motherboard Asus Maximus IX Hero, in Ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: @JonathanY. apparently this motherboard is shipping with a bad driver checksum, also on same hardware and affected.

Comment: @NaftuliKay, what do you mean by "driver checksum"? I thought the contents of the LAN NVM is not a "driver", it's more like firmware. In Intel's datasheet it is referred to as "LAN image" or just "LAN NVM".

Comment: I have [developed a Python tool](https://gist.github.com/naftulikay/0b48e9236f9b91529296ecc5c9333dc1) which validates that an NVM checksum is valid. It's not super easy to validate, so this script will at least tell you whether yours is valid or not. FWIW, simply writing `0xff` to `0x10` caused my checksum word to bounce back such that the sum equaled `0xbaba`. Hope this helps the next MAXIMUS IX Hero user.

Comment: "simply writing `0xff`" -- that is exactly the solution under which you are commenting.

Comment: Do not do this, this may render your hardware useless. Use Intel `bootutil`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, can you explain what you mean?  Whom are you addressing?  By the way, in my question i already said that Intel does not advise using `bootutil` with OEM hardware.

Comment: @Alexey I am referring to your post. It is a nice investigation, however, the method is dangerous in that it requires magic numbers and random offsets. Your method might brick the NIC. Intel tool `bootutil` recognises the hardware and does its job correctly, as the other posters reported.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, the other poster reported that it (magically) worked for them, while it was never recommended by Intel and they probably do not know what `bootutil` does. You are free of course to upvote their answers or leave them a comment.  In this answer I explained in detail how i fixed the problem myself.  Your comment looks absurd to me (whom were you addressing? who can render their hardware useless? which hardware? how do you know this?).  Note also that in this answer i was not giving any recommendations.

Comment: I was commenting on your post, not someone else's comment, do not be silly.

Comment: [With regards to `bootutil`](https://communities.intel.com/community/wired/blog/2010/07/16/bootutil-the-super-preboot-tool): _BootUtil replaces existing utilities and provides the functionality of the older IBAUTIL, ISCSIUTL, LANUTIL, and FLAUTIL... __BootUtil without command line options will display a list of all supported Intel network ports in the system.___ In other words, if `bootutil` lists your NIC, then it supports it.

Comment: Your answer requires firstly compiling a patched driver and installing it. And then using `ethtool` to write a random value at a random location in NICs NVM, which may brick your NIC (different hardware revision, different firmware version, etc.). Therefore, your solution is too complicated and carries unnecessary risks. The right solution is using `bootutil` provided by Intel, the manufacturer of the NIC and its firmware. Quit trolling mate.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, using `ethtool` to write *the same value* (which was there before) to a *specific* location (the one chosen by me).  If you read my answer carefully, you will notice that everything in it is true (if you trust my account) and there is no unjustified claims. Also, it contains no recommendations about how others should deal with such a problem.

Comment: Looks like the e1000 driver actually has built in tools to help (maybe fix? I'm not a programmer) now - http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000/e1000_main.c#L757

Answer (score 9):

I used `bootutil` for Linux from Intel (as suggested in the 2011 post) on an integrated Intel NIC on my Asus Z270-A to fix this error, without the recompiling and magic keys discussed in the upvoted answer. It worked great. I downloaded the tool from the [Intel download site](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19186)

```sh
chmod +x ./bootutil64e
sudo ./bootutil64e -NIC 1 -defcfg
```

Comment: I suppose you mean [this 2011 post](https://thesorcerer.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/guide-intel-82573l-gigabit-ethernet-with-ubuntu-11-04-and-fix-pxe-e05/) and you suggest other users to disregard the disclaimer at the end at their own risk.  Nice to know it worked for you in any case.

Comment: No. That 2011 post is way out of date, asks you to create a DOS thumb drive, etc. You don't need to rebuild any drivers or make thumb drives. You can simply use the tool. It is "at your own risk", but I suspect that is simply to satisfy the lawyers.

Comment: What "No" is about? Are you talking about a different 2011 post?

Comment: This is the right method.

Comment: This worked for me on a Thinkpad T60

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error on Fedora 24 from `e1000e` driver with ASUS ROG MAXIMUS IX HERO motherboard which has Intel I219-V NIC adapter.

I find the accepted solution, that requires patching the NVM, too risky. It may render your hardware useless.

One safe solution is to apply the default configuration to the NIC using [Intel Ethernet Connections Boot Utility](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19186/Intel-Ethernet-Connections-Boot-Utility-Preboot-Images-and-EFI-Drivers). It works in Linux out of the box, no need to create a boot disk:

```
$ chmod +x bootutil64e
$ sudo ./bootutil64e -NIC=1 -DEFAULTCONFIG
```

That is it. Just reboot (or re-load `e1000e` driver manually).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and wanted to try everything else before playing with NVM bits.

I am not sure that this was what solved the problem, but the last thing I did before it magically worked again was **attempt to boot over the network with UEFI (IPv4)**. Then some black magic must have fixed my NVM.

#### Environment

- Mainboard: Asus PRIME Z270-A (BIOS 0701)
- NIC: `00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [8086:15b8]`

Answer (score 1):

My solution is much more simple:
- enter the UEFI BIOS utility;
- enter *Advanced mode*
- navigate to *Advanced\Network Stack Configuration* and simply enable the network stack (i only enabled IPv4 to remain safely behind my NAT).
Reboot and enjoy your NIC. Apparently this is enough to somehow clear the bad NVM checksum. You can then go back and disable said stack.
**This is under BIOS version 8001 on an Asus Prime z270-a motherboard (e1000e driver on Arch Linux, kernel 4.9.11-1).**
Perhaps what caused this issue whas that i tried updating the firmware via internet directly via the EZ Flash utility (and failing to do so for both DHCP and static IP modes). I remember the utility asking whether it could enable the network stack (which is off by default) in order to attempt the update.

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately, i cannot test this, as the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$ sudo ./bootutil64e -NIC=XXX -BOOTENABLE=DISABLED.
```

This should do the trick in recent versions of `bootutil64e`.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for your solution, please? (That it is recommended / safe / expected to work.)

Comment: I suppose that works great because it is one of simpler options to change, but still enough to recalculate NVM checksum. I have used the wake-on-LAN option. One can, of course, check current WOL status first, then flip it and change it back again to the original value.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue after a BIOS update when doing a bare metal install of Gentoo. (MSI Z390-PRO-A Motherboard)

The network was initially fine, but the BIOS update must have done something to corrupt the onboard I219-V.

But a combination of the answers from pparadox and Daniel Höxtermann, fixed it for me.

I drilled down to the Network Stack configuration in my BIOS, saved and rebooted.  Once the BIOS logo came up, I then pressed F11 to get the boot menu, and selected the IPV4 UEFI PXE Boot.

I let it timeout, and then rebooted, and again pressed F11 when the option came up, and selected my normal boot device.

It came up with a working on board NIC!

After that I returned to the BIOS and disabled the Network Stack, and the NIC kept working after I returned to the Gentoo install.